# Connecting stdin/stdout to a network port on Windows

Tags: windows, linux, sockets, client-server, inetd

I've written a server software that uses stdin/stdout to communicate with the client side. On Linux and similar systems, I use inetd to define what port my program should respond, and then inetd will take care of answering any incoming calls and connecting the socket with stdin/stdout of my program. What is the easiest way for me to accomplish this in windows?

Comment: http://xmailserver.org/wininetd.html

Comment: I tried wininetd, but I can't get it to work. I could bang my head against it some more, but I was hoping there existed alternative solutions.

Comment: There are others - cygwin, http://www.webiso.be/inetd.htm, probably more.

Comment: Ok, wininetd works fine. That will do. Still, I'm surprised that there is not a native feature like that in windows.